# Flow rate of Venturimeter $v=\sqrt{\left(\frac{2\left(P_{1}-P_{2}\right)}{\rho}\right)}\left[\left(\frac{A}{a}\right)^{2}-1\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation, medical-physics

How to derive $$v=\sqrt{\left(\frac{2\left(P_{1}-P_{2}\right)}{\rho}\right)}\left[\left(\frac{A}{a}\right)^{2}-1\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}~?$$ I came across it while studying fluids mechanics in medicine and I am not sure how to derive it. It is related to Venturi effect. I tried using equation of continuity $Av=av'$ and Bernoulli's theorem  $$P_1+ \rho gh_1+ ½\rho v^2=P_2+ \rho gh_2+ ½\rho v'^2$$ but to no avail. How is it related to Venturi effect?

Comment: Hint: you're on the right track. Use Bernoulli, neglect height change, and put velocity in terms of mass flow rate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tube narrows (i.e  $a<A$) we   have Bernoulli
$$
\frac 12 v_1^2 +\frac{P_1}{\rho}= \frac 12 v_2^2+ \frac {P_2}{\rho}.
$$
Using mass conservation  $Av_1=av_2$ this becomes
$$ 
\frac 12 v_1^2 +\frac{P_1}{\rho}= \frac 12 v_1^2\left(\frac A a\right)+ \frac {P_2}{\rho},
$$
which is easily arranged into your formula for $v\equiv v_1$.